# navigation issue : PopToRootAsync is not supported globally on iOS, please use a NavigationPage

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

On App class I have this :

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

In MainPage OnAppearing :

```
protected async override void OnAppearing ()
    {
        base.OnAppearing ();

        if (TempUserInfo.IsNewUser ())
            await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync ( new SignUpPage ());
    }
```

On SignUpPage after user enters all information , I use this :

```
await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync (new VerificationCodePage());
```

Finally , after I check verification code on VerificationPage I used this:

```
await this.Navigation.PopToRootAsync ();
```

Now , I'm getting this error :

PopToRootAsync is not supported globally on iOS, please use a NavigationPage.

**What I want to achieve is exactly like this navigation setup above .**

Comment: Do you think if I use library like MVVMLight would help in this situation? I remember it has different options of navigation . Just thinking...

Comment: you've done 2 PushModalAsync, so you need to to do 2 PopModalAync, then PopToRootAsync.

Comment: If I do PopModalAsyn from VerificationPage , this will send me back to SignUpPage !! instead i want to pop to main page.

Comment: That's why you need to do 2 PopModals.  If you don't like that, then redesign your Navigation.  One possibility is to detect the new user in your App class, and navigate directly to the Signup.  Once signup is complete, instead of navigating to MainPage, just completely swap out App.MainPage.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing

```
await this.Navigation.PopToRootAsync ();
```

You can reset the main page :

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

Answer (score 1):

I resigned navigation to what Jason suggested and in the VerificationPage , I used this :

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

Thanks everyone for your help .

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked as i expected on Android. Put these in App.xaml.cs

```
 public static MyMasterDetail RootPage()
{
    return (MyMasterDetail)Current.MainPage;
}

public static void NavigateToHomePage()
{
    try
    {


        MainPage homePage = new MainPage();
        MyMasterDetail masterDetailRootPage = (MyMasterDetail)Application.Current.MainPage;
        masterDetailRootPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(homePage);
        masterDetailRootPage.IsPresented = false;

        Current.MainPage = masterDetailRootPage;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("!!! NavigateToHomePage() Exception !!!");
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception Description: " + ex);
    }
}
```

Then you could call from anywhere to go home

```
   App.NavigateToHomePage();
```

Or show masterdetail left side menu

```
   App.RootPage().IsPresented = true;
```